# Filter data by month

Tags: c#, linq

I've a source data which contains the data in month as below:

```
Oct 2011
Nov 2011
Dec 2011
Jan 2012
Feb 2012
```

I need to select all the months that invoice falls on to. The invoice has properties below:

```
Invoice.StartDate=13-10-2011;
Invoice.EndDate=11-01-2012;


sourceData.Where(x => x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month && 
                 x.SourceDate.Year==Invoice.StartDate.Year && 
                 x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month &&
                 x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year).ToList();
```

The above query returns 0. I'm expecting the filtered data source result below:

```
Oct 2011
Nov 2011
Dec 2011
Jan 2012
```

Could someone help me to achieve above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution simply creates `DateTime`s with `Day` set to 0 so they can be compared directly.  It uses query syntax because it's more convenient for creating the new `DateTime`s.

```
startYearMonth = new DateTime(Invoice.StartDate.Year, Invoice.StartDate.Month, 0);
endYearMonth = new DateTime(Invoice.EndDate.Year, Invoice.EndDate.Month, 0);

(from data in sourceData
 let dataYearMonth = new DateTime(data.SourceDate.Year, data.SourceDate.Month, 0)
 where dataYearMonth >= startYearMonth && dataYearMonth <= endYearMonth
 select data).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The year is unique. 2011 or 2012.
But your where clause sets impossible option.

```
x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.StartDate.Year && x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year
```

is same with

```
x.SourceDate.Year == 2011 && x.SourceDate.Year == 2012
```

How about this?

```
sourceData.Where(x => (x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month && 
    x.SourceDate.Year==Invoice.StartDate.Year) || 
    (x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month &&
    x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year)).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it won't work if I want to retrieve data for Oct 2011
Nov 2011
Dec 2011

Answer (score 1):

You handled the case where the year is equal, but you also have to handle the case where the year is greater than the start year and the case where the year is less than the end year:

```
sourceData.Where(x => (x.SourceDate.Year > Invoice.StartDate.Year ||
                      (x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month && 
                      x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.StartDate.Year)) && 
                      (x.SourceDate.Year < Invoice.EndDate.Year ||
                      (x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month &&
                      x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year))).ToList();
```

This solution is not that readable and is easy to get wrong, but it is closest to your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks for data where:

x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month
AND
x.SourceDate.Year==Invoice.StartDate.Year
AND
x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month
AND
x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year

None of you data meets all of these criteria, you should be looking for the following:

(x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month AND x.SourceDate.Year==Invoice.StartDate.Year)
OR
(x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month AND x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year)

Like this:

```
sourceData.Where(x => (x.SourceDate.Month >= Invoice.StartDate.Month &&  
             x.SourceDate.Year==Invoice.StartDate.Year) ||  
             (x.SourceDate.Month <= Invoice.EndDate.Month && 
             x.SourceDate.Year == Invoice.EndDate.Year)).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it won't work if I want to retrieve data for Oct 2011
Nov 2011
Dec 2011

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do a date comparison? I'm not sure if the values in your source table are actual date items, but you can always use the `Date()` constructor to build proper dates if necessary.

```
sourceData.Where(x => x.SourceDate >= Invoice.StartDate && 
                 x.SourceDate <= Invoice.EndDate ).ToList();
```